# why does as.character(pi) has more digits than pi?

Tags: r

Why does R's built-in constant `pi` has more digits if printed as numeric than if printed as character?

```r
> pi
[1] 3.141593

> as.character(pi)
[1] "3.14159265358979"

> as.numeric(as.character(pi))
[1] 3.141593
```

Comment: How an object is *represented* (printed) on the console may be completely different than how it is *stored*. Consider `options(digits=3); pi; options(digits=9); pi;`. So `as.character` is just using a number of decimal places; one can go further with `format(pi, digits=22)`. None of that changes that `pi` is an irrational number and stored with as much precision internally as R can manage.

Comment: as.character (pi) has the same number of digits as its numerical version, only r prints 6 digits by default. Use for example `sprintf("%.14f",as.numeric(as.character(pi)))`